# Perl API for getting site domain

Tags: perl, country-codes

I was wondering if there's a Perl API I can use that would get 'co.uk' or '.de'. I want to map the country code onto a site domain to redirect people.

so if the country code is 'gb', then I'd redirect to .co.uk, without having to hardcode this in for every country.

Comment: Are you using PSGI? Have you looked at CPAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core module [Locale::Country](http://perldoc.perl.org/Locale/Country.html) has a mapping from locales to top level domains.